# ASP.NET issues request for the Logon_User

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I simply created a strong variable requesting for the session's logon_name. Reason why I did this is because the logon_name gives me for example daniel.ellison and the username variable gives me T12345 (our company's employee ID). If I switched the @logon_name to @username and change my DB's user name value to my employee's ID it works fine. BUt when I switch my DB's username back to daniel.ellison and switch it back to @logon_name it fails. Any idea why that would be?

```
<%@ import namespace="System.Data" %> 
<%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient" %> 
<%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection" %> 

    <Script runat="server"> 
        Sub page_load()
            Dim username As String = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))
            Dim logon_name As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
            Dim dbconn As MySqlConnection
            Dim mySqlCommand As MySqlCommand
            Dim counter As Integer
            Dim isInGroup As Boolean
            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = @logon_name AND group_id = 1001;"

            dbconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=imc_directory_tool;user=Directory_Admin;port=3306;password=IMCisgreat2014;")
            dbconn.Open()

            mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, dbconn)
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logon_name", username)
            counter = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
            isInGroup = counter > 0
            If isInGroup = True Then
                Response.Write(logon_name)
                Response.Write("You are part of group_id 1001")
            Else
                Response.Write(logon_name)
                Response.Write("You are not part of group_id 1001")
            End If
            dbconn.Close()
        End Sub
    </Script>
```

Comment: Have you used a breakpoint and checked that you get the correct values for username and logon_name... If I run this I get username = surname.firstname and logon_name = domain\surname.firstname

Comment: Yeah i did a response.write and getting daniel.ellison without the domain prefix (ie: ad\daniel.ellison) this is why i find it strange. Ill double check again to make sure.

Comment: THis is so weird, I tried again and when doing Response.Write(logon_name) I get back AD\T12355 (employee ID). This is the preWindows 2000 user name. Would anyone know how to get the entered/submitted username? When users login they would use first.last_name and not their pre-windows 200 login name.